# Compute mean coordinates

Tags: geometry, coordinates, analysis

Can anybody explain how to compute **mean coordinates**?

Comment: please clarify your question. What exactly are you try to do and what tools are you using?

Comment: I am using the analysis tool whose name is mean coordinate.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I am using Quantum GIS.

Comment: This question describes how to compute mean coordinates in QGIS: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29181/mean-coordinates-in-qgis.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, but in this post is not explained how is computed the mean coordinate ...

Answer (score 6):

The same way you calculate any mean from a set of numbers.  The sum of the numbers divided by the count

```
Mean x = (X1 + X2 + X3....XN)/N
Mean Y = (Y1 + Y2 + Y3....YN)/N
```

Comment: I suppose there should be another possibilities, arithmetic mean is only relevant for planar coordinates.

Comment: True, although with the lack of information in the question I just assumed planar.

Comment: You are right. AFAIC, doing it on the sphere and/or on the ellipse (I think of WGS84) are also relevant. I also think of Delaunay Triangles, Voronoï Diagrams and the more involved computations implied.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  
In WGS 84 are the same calculations?? Is correct to do this in every coordinate system or projection?